# Question about two description of the algebraic $\alpha$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am learning the Fields extension but I have one question about the algebraic $\alpha$.

Let $K$ be a extension of a field $F$, and let $\alpha$ be an element of $K$. We say $\alpha$ is **algebraic** over $F$, if is a root of a monic polynomial with coefficients in $F$. In Artin's textbook, it says that the two possibilities for $\alpha$ can be described in terms of the substitutional homomorphism:
$$
\phi: F[x]\to K, \mbox{ defined by } x\to \alpha
$$

**Question 1**: why can we say if $\alpha$ is algebraic, then $\phi$ is not injective?

If $\alpha$ is **algebraic**, then
$$
f(\alpha)=\alpha^n+a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}+\dots+a_1\alpha+a_0=0, a_i\in F
$$

I did not see the reason.

**Question 2**: Suppose that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$. Why "**$F[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, the kernel of $\phi$ is a principal ideal, generated by a monic polynomial $f(x)$ with coefficients in $F$**?"

I know the definition of principal ideal domain and principal ideal:

**Principal ideal domain**: An **integral domain** $R$, or just a domain, is a ring with this property: $R$ is not the zero ring, and if $a$ and $b$ are elements of $R$ whose product $ab$ is zero, then $a=0$ or $b=0$. An integral domain in which every ideal is principal is called a **principal ideal domain**.

**Principal ideal**: In any ring $R$, the multiples of a particular element $a$ form an ideal called the principal ideal generated by $a$. Write $(a)=aR=Ra=\{ra: r\in R\}$.

Comment: What is the definition of "$\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$"?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Let $K$ be a extension of a field $F$, and let $\alpha$ be an element of $K$. We say $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$, if is a root of a monic polynomial with coefficients in $F$.

Comment: $f(x)=x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots + a_1x+a_0$ is not the zero polynomial, but $\phi(f)=0=\phi(0_F)$, where $0_F$ is the zero polynomial. So two different inputs $f,0_F$, have the same image under $\phi$. Hence $\phi$ is not injective.

Comment: @user114263 I know what an algebraic number is, I'm asking the OP to give the definition that his textbook is using. And if you are going to do that, then perhaps give a correct definition? It's not "the solution", it is "a root"; and it's not "**a** polynomial", it's "a **nonzero** polynomial").]

Comment: The definition is in the question.

Comment: @user114263 The definition was added 3 minutes ago. I asked 7 minutes ago. Do try to keep your foot out of your mouth.

Comment: Do try not to be an asshole

Comment: @user114263 says the guy giving incorrect responses and implications. Don't pollute the information ecosphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ring homomorphism is one-to-one if and only if its kernel is trivial.

If $\alpha$ is algebraic, then there exists a monic polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$. In particular, if $\alpha$ is algebraic, then $\phi(f)=0$. Since $f$ is monic, $f\neq 0$, so $\ker(\phi)\neq(0)$, hence $\phi$ is not injective.

(Conversely, if $\phi$ is not injective then there exists $f(x)\in F[x]$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$ and $\phi(f)=f(\alpha)=0$; dividing through by the leading coefficient of $f$ you get a monic polynomial $\mathfrak{f}(x)\in F[x]$ such that $\mathfrak{f}(\alpha)=0$, so $\alpha$ is algebraic. Thus, $\alpha$ is algebraic if and only if $\phi$ is not injective.)

The fact that $F[x]$ is a PID whenever $F$ is a field should have already been established. Since $\ker(\phi)$ is an ideal, it is principal, so there exists $g(x)\in F[x]$ such that $\ker(\phi)=(g)$. Because $g(x)\neq 0$ (since $\ker(\phi)\neq(0)$), it has leading coefficient $a_n\neq 0$. Then $a_n$ is a unit in $F[x]$, so $(g(x)) = (\frac{1}{a_n}g(x)) = \ker(\phi)$. But $\frac{1}{a_n}g(x)$ is monic. So set $f(x) = \frac{1}{a_n}g(x)$ to get that $\ker(\phi)$ is generated by a monic polynomial. The fact that it lies in $F[x]$ tells you it has coefficients in $F$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the map $\phi$ is homomorphism? But why $\phi(f)=0$? That is because $f(\alpha)=0$?

Comment: @Hermi: Yes; that should already have been established. It's the universal property of $F[x]$: given any ring homomorphism $f\colon F\to R$ to a commutative ring, and any $r\in R$, the map sending $a_nx^n+\cdots +a_1x + a_0$ to $f(a_n)r^n + \cdots + f(a_1)r + f(a_0)$ is a ring homomorphism. Here you have the inclusion $F\hookrightarrow K$ and the the element $\alpha\in K$.